# Shortcut key to select word in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keyboard shortcut to select a word? Or may be it can be assigned some how?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> selects enclosing elements.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> reverses <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> selects enclosing elements moving **up** the file.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> selects enclosing elements moving **down** the file.

Comment: Use Shift + Control + arrows on the Mac.

Comment: It seems these bindings are broken in Kepler (Version: 4.3.1.v20130911-1000, Build id: M20130911-1000). I guess it might be due to the fact they use arrow keys and it seems there are problems with shortcuts using these keys for some time now. See for instance https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=376491

Comment: For Ubuntu it's also Shift+Ctrl

Comment: I think the answer isn't exactly. I am using Eclipse Luna 4.4

Comment: I'm using Kepler Service Release 1 on Windows and shift+alt+arrow selects just fine. I'm using Luna on Mac and the equivalent selection does nothing. Presumably this functionality has been broken in Luna (or earlier).

Comment: Would be the reverse actually? Currently I am wondering if there is something like "deselect enclosing elements"

Answer (score 31):

The quickest way to find any keyboard shortcut in Eclipse is to use Help->Key Assist (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>), which will pop up a nice tooltip with keyboard shortcuts and what they do. (If you press he Key Assist shortcut twice, you'll get the Keys Preferences page, which allows you to reassign shortcuts.)

```
String |myFancyString = "FooBar";
```

If your cursor is immediately to the left of 'm' (I am indicating this with a pipe (|)) :

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> (Select Next Element) would select 'myFancyString'
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> (Select Previous Element) would also select 'myFancyString'
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> (Select Next Word) would select 'my', repeating it would select 'myFancy', followed by 'myFancyString '

Comment: Thank you Joshua for that info!

Comment: Do you know the difference between the three commands (Select Next|Previous|Enclosing element)? It seems they extend the selection with the same result in all situations I throw.

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> selects the word surrounding the cursor

Answer (score 3):

To select, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + any arrow key.