# Word Selection by Double Clicking in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I double-click the word "Annotation" below the @ is also selected.

```
@Annotation
```

Is there a configuration option to change this?  I only want the word "Annotation" selected, and not the @ sign.

Comment: Wouldn't this be more appropriate for [su]? Also I think you should clarify the platform you are in.

Comment: I thought the behavior is pretty much OS dependent.

Comment: The life of a programmer is so hard...

Comment: @Martjin: No; Eclipse would have its own handling.

Answer (score 2):

Dear you should use these controls to select the word annotation

```
shift+alt+up
```

after this you will be able to select the world

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to select it via mouse. But if you keep cursor anywhere within `Annotation` and Use

Shift+Alt+Up

it should just select `Annotation`

Please see this as well [Shortcut key to select word in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049834/shortcut-key-to-select-word-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that there is such a configuration option in Eclipse.